# Python paho client with tls fails with OSError

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have mosquito setup with SSL enabled & clients are connecting using client certificate. Following is the code I use

```
    print('Connecting to MQTT broker')
    self.mqtt_client = mqtt.Client(protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311)
    mqtt_addr = self.config_dict['MQTT']['mqtt_addr']
    mqtt_port = self.config_dict['MQTT']['mqtt_port']
    cert_topic = self.config_dict['MQTT']['cert_topic']
    ca_certificate = self.config_dict['certificates']['mqtt_ca']
    init_certificate = self.config_dict['certificates']['mqtt_cert']
    init_key = self.config_dict['certificates']['mqtt_key']
    self.mqtt_client.tls_set(ca_certs=ca_certificate,
                             certfile=init_certificate,
                             keyfile=init_key,
                             cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                             tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,
                             ciphers=None)
    self.mqtt_client.tls_insecure_set(True)
```

But once in awhile client failed to connect to broker with following

```
Connecting to MQTT broker
mosquitto.dev.example.com
8883
example/device/{}/cert
cert_store_dev/ca.crt
cert_store_dev/client.crt
cert_store_dev/client.key
Exception occurred while connecting, subscribing andpublishing registration request on MQTT broker.
Unexpected error: [Errno 0] Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "device_status.py", line 144, in <module>
    init_ds.send_device_status()
  File "device_status.py", line 107, in send_device_status
    self.verify_status_response(res)
  File "device_status.py", line 132, in verify_status_response
    self.dr_ins.initiate_registration()
  File "/home/ubuntu/device/field_device/device_registration.py", line 120, in initiate_registration
    self.set_mqtt_client(dev_uuid)
  File "/home/ubuntu/device/field_device/device_registration.py", line 99, in set_mqtt_client
    self.mqtt_client.connect(host=mqtt_addr, port=int(mqtt_port))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 937, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1100, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

If I run this multiple time it works. What's wrong in this code ?